# Upgrade extension with custom project types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I have extension with custom project type. This project is in VS 2012, based on MPF12 and everything is working fine. I am trying to upgrade it to VS 2013 project. Upgrading goes fine, but when I run the project and try to create project of my custom type I get the following error:
[image]

Exception occured in class `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.Automation.OAProject` in `ConfigurationManager` property getter in this line of code:
`ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(extensibility.GetConfigMgr(this.project.InteropSafeIVsHierarchy, VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, out configurationManagerAsObject));`
Exception message:
The input IVsHierarchy is not expected, please ensure to pass the correct IVsHierarchy object. A common mistake would be the stub proxy was passed when the method was invoked on a background thread.

And after exception code come back in class `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.ProjectFactory` in method `CreateProject` in this line:
`int hr = aggregateProjectFactory.CreateAggregateProject(guidsList, fileName, location, name, flags, ref projectGuid, out project);` hr is assgined to -2147024809 and after that transformed to exception which is saying about frameworkName.

I couldnt find information about where should I define this frameworkName. Project is defined using .vstemplate template file.

Here is sample application: http://ge.tt/394l48U1/v/0. To run it go to `\Samples\CSharp` folder. `CustomProject` is the original sample project, it is working fine. `CustomProjectUnzipppp` - changed project, whihc is using .vstemplate - got error there.

Comment: Enabling "break on exception" and posting the stack trace might be informative.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski thx for advice. Ive provided more information about occuring erorrs.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski could you please take a look at sample, which Ive uploaded?